# How do I add a piece of string from one df column to another in python/pandas?

Tags: python, string, pandas

I'm working in a pandas dataframe consisting of 10.000+ links to newspaper-article.  I would like to use the part of the string in my links displaying the subject/editorial of the articles, e.g /media/ or /sport/, to another column.

Example: 
Col 1 contains these links:
www.theguardian.com/us-news/wikileaks-during-final-stages-of-election
www.theguardian.com/politics/parliament-to-have-final-

I.e. I want to make a def which iterates over the strings in Col 1 and if a string contains "/us-news/" then "US News" is added Col 2, just as if a string contains /politics/ then "Politics" is added ti Col 2.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`numpy.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) with conditions by [`str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html):

```
m1 = df['col1'].str.contains('/us-news/')
m2 = df['col1'].str.contains('/politics/')

df['col2'] = np.select([m1,m2], ['US News','Politics'], default='no match')
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick answer - worked perfectly!